# Keep tclsh open after running script through notepad++

Tags: shell, script, notepad++

I'm currently writing a tcl script using Notepad++.

I've edited the F5 key such `C:\TCL\bin\tclsh.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

This will open a tcl shell & run the current script I am writing.
I want the shell to stay open after the script has executed.
I know I can leave a request for input etc...but after input the shell will just close...again, not what i want. I want to be able to edit & make use of the interpreter....query variables etc.

Thanks,
WesleyTaylor

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
gets stdin
```

at the end of the script. This will cause the script to wait for input before exiting.